# Can I turn off impersonation just in a couple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I have an app that has impersonation used throughout.  But when a user is logged in as an admin, a few operation require them to write to the server itself.  Now if these users do not have rights on the actual server (some don't) it will not let them write.

What I want to do is turn off impersonation for just a couple commands.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
using(HostingEnvironment.Impersonate.Off())
  //I know this isn't a command, but you get the idea?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure the Application Pool do have the proper rights that you need.

Then, when you want to revert to the application pool identity... run the following:

```
private WindowsImpersonationContext context = null;
public void RevertToAppPool()
{
    try
    {
        if (!WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem)
        {
            context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
public void UndoImpersonation()
{
    try
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Undo();
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the preferred approach but when I wanted to do this I new'd up an instance of a [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) and called the [Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate.aspx) method.  This allows subsequent code to impersonate a different Windows user. It returns a [WindowsImpersonationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx) that has an [Undo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.undo.aspx) method which reverts the impersonation context back again.

Comment: Is there any way you know of that I can call the default web_app account without specifying it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off authentication for the page and then manually impersonate the authenticated user during the remainder of your code.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

This has a reference to that last part, but basically you impersonate User.Identity

This will mean you will have to impersonate at the beginning of any call to the page, turn it off when you need it off, then turn it back on when you are done, but it should be a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up giving the folders write permissions to "Authenticated Users"

Comment: That works too. But it leaves some huge security risk. Because even anonymous users would be able to write to that folder. I highly suggest that you make yourself a class that revert to the Application Pool identity. Then use that instance to under the revert.