# Insert Error:Cannot open database "xxxx" requested by the login

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi I am coming across an error when trying to insert data into database from a form I have created on a web page:

Comment: Possible duplicate.  See if the answer on this one works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879647/sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-network-service

Answer (score 1):

The user 'PC/User' doesn't have the right permissions for the Database.

A simple Google search of your title would have yielded results such as this:

[SQL Authority Blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I have always had better luck with initial catalog rather than the .mdf file.

Another option is to go to the properties on the data source (in server explorer) and copy the connection string from there.

```
<add name="MyConsString"
    connection string=&quot;
    data source=ServerName\SQLEXPRESS;
    initial catalog=BlogData;
    integrated security=True;
    multipleactiveresultsets=True;
    App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```