# Temporarily disable impersonation in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp-classic, impersonation

I'm coding an intranet system that writes files locally to the webserver, through a script using `ADODB.Stream`. The problem is, it uses the logged Windows/AD user account to do so, as impersonation is activated by default in IIS - and I actually need it activated most of the time. Since I don't want to give write access to the webserver to anyone that needs to make use of the system, I need to temporarily "unimpersonate" the session back to the "IUSR" account.

How could I do that? Preferentially in classic ASP, as the whole site is coded in it, but could be something in ASP.net (C#) too.

I work for a large company, and my access to the IIS control panel/server machine is a bit limited (need to deal with another department). And I can't install any custom modules or DLLs either.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125096/can-i-turn-off-impersonation-just-in-a-couple-instances. Though it's done in C# and not Classic ASP.

Comment: What version of IIS is involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got around the impersonation problem in a different way. Just wrote an ASP.net script to save files using `HttpPostedFile`, based [on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269639/2631982), and it worked like a charm. The files are (probably) being written under the app pool user configured in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used the `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP` to make a server-side call that switches the impersonation context using the HTTP Authorization Headers. This allows me to create a file using a different context to what the website is running in.

```vb
Sub ExecuteContext(url, data, user, password)
  Dim http

  Set http = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  Response.CharSet = "utf-8"

  Call http.open("POST", url, False, user, password)

  'Called using Basic Authentication (not as secure as Windows Authenticated by should be adequate)
  Call http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(user & ":" & password))
  Call http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  Call http.send(data)
End Sub

'Supporting functions to do the Base64 encoded Authorization header.
Function Base64Encode(inData)
  'ripped from: 
  'http://www.pstruh.cz/tips/detpg_Base64Encode.htm
  'rfc1521
  '2001 Antonin Foller, PSTRUH Software, http://pstruh.cz
  Const Base64 = _
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  Dim sOut, I

  'For each group of 3 bytes
  For I = 1 To Len(inData) Step 3
    Dim nGroup, pOut

    'Create one long from this 3 bytes.
    nGroup = &H10000 * Asc(Mid(inData, I, 1)) + _
      &H100 * MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 1, 1)) + _
      MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 2, 1))

    'Oct splits the long To 8 groups with 3 bits
    nGroup = Oct(nGroup)

    'Add leading zeros
    nGroup = String(8 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup

    'Convert To base64
    pOut = Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
      Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
      Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
      Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 7, 2)) + 1, 1)

    'Add the part To OutPut string
    sOut = sOut + pOut

  Next
  Select Case Len(inData) Mod 3
    Case 1: '8 bit final
      sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 2) + "=="
    Case 2: '16 bit final
      sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1) + "="
  End Select
  Base64Encode = sOut
End Function

Function MyASC(OneChar)
  If OneChar = "" Then MyASC = 0 Else MyASC = Asc(OneChar)
End Function
```

This approach is extremely flexible, in my implementation I use to it to change the context in the same page by POSTing to itself but with different `data`.

Comment: I've already found the answer myself, but I'm upvoting this as it's an very interesting technique.