# Implement Impersonation for specific users

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, impersonation

I am creating a website and I want to give certain users the ability to maintain the content (create new pages, update pages, add documents, etc.).  I have set the default account for the app pool to only have read / execute permissions.  I needed a way to grant write permissions to only a few people who login to the website.  I searched and found these two articles:

[Can I turn off impersonation just in a couple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125096/can-i-turn-off-impersonation-just-in-a-couple-instances)

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158

I followed the code example in the microsoft article under the section "Impersonate a Specific User in Code".

This worked.

Both of these articles are older though, so I wanted to see if anyone had any concerns with this method (specifically security concerns).

My server is Windows 2008R2 (IIS 7.5).  I am using .NET 4.5.1 with c#.

Comment: personally I would stay away from Impersonation and implement some other approach for example `User Rights / Rolls` or you could create your own using database.. there are several approached to this without using Impersonation..

Comment: Support article you've linked to still applies. There are always security concerns around authentication/authorization, but it is not clear what kind of concerns you are looking for.

Comment: MethodMan:  Your example "User Rights / Rolls"; I am not familiar with this approach.  Could you provide a link to documentation?  Thanks.